# Summing up an ArrayList with multiple types

Tags: java, arraylist, types

I am having trouble summing up my `ArrayList` that I made in my class `Treasureroom` which is in my class `Accountant`. I have an `ArrayList` with type `Valuable` as you can see in the code below. I need to be able to sum up all the `int` elements from within the `Accountant` class.

**Accountant**

```
package Accountant;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

import ValuableFactory.Valuable;
import rw.RWMonitor;
import rw.Treasureroom;

public class Accountant implements Runnable {
    private Treasureroom treasureroom; 
    private static final int MAX_WAIT_TIME = 10000; // 3 seconds
    private static final int MAX_WORK_TIME = 5000; // 2 seconds

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private int no;
    private RWMonitor monitor;
    private Treasureroom resource;

    public Accountant( int no, RWMonitor monitor, Treasureroom resource ) {
        this.no = no;
        this.monitor = monitor;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(WAIT_TIME));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            System.out.println("Accountant counts: " + resource);

            monitor.acquireRead();

            //System.out.println("Accountant counted: " + valuable);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(MAX_WAIT_TIME));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            for (int i = 0; i > resource.)
                System.out.println("Accountant counted: " + resource.getValueRead());

            monitor.releaseRead();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(WAIT_AGAIN));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

 //System.out.println("The total sum of TreasureRoom is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
 //TreasureRoom.releaseRead();

}
```

**Treasureroom**

```
package rw;

import java.util.*;
import ValuableFactory.*;

public class Treasureroom {
    ArrayList<Valuable> valuables = new ArrayList<Valuable>();

    public Valuable getValueWriter() {
        return valuables.remove(0);
    }

    public void updateValue(Valuable valuable) {
        valuables.add(valuable);
    }

    public boolean removeValue(Valuable valuable) {
        return valuables.remove(valuable);
    }

    public Valuable getValueReade() {
        for (int i=0; i<valuables.size();i++) {
            return valuables.get(i); 
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Valuable**

```
package ValuableFactory;

public class Valuable implements ValuableFactory {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public Valuable(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name; 
        this.value = value; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `valuables.stream().mapToInt(Valuable::getValue).sum()`

Comment: But where do you put it, because i can not call the ArrayList in the "Accountant" class

Comment: What is your `getValueReade()` method in `Treasureroom` supposed to do? It will always return the first `Valuable` in the room or `null` if it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Accountant` class instantiates your `Treasureroom` object in its constructor, meaning that to loop through the `ArrayList` inside the `Treasureroom` object using an `Accountant` object you would need a method in `Accountant` that calls a method in `Treasureroom`.

## Accountant

```
public int getTreasureSum()
{
    return resource.sumTreasure();
}
```

## Treasureroom

```
public int sumTreasure()
{
    int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < valuables.size(); i++)
        {
            sum+= valuables.get(i).getValue();
        }

    return sum;
}
```

Also in your `Accountant` class you have an unused `Treasureroom` object

```
private Treasureroom treasureroom;
```